# How do i get the value present in first double quotes?

Tags: bash, shell, awk, sed

I'm currently writing a bash script to get the first value among the many comma separated strings.
I have a file that looks like this -

```
name


things: "water bottle","40","new phone cover",10



place
```

I just need to return the value in first double quotes.

```
water bottle
```

The value in first double quotes can be one word/two words. That is, `water bottle` can be sometimes replaced with `pen`.
I tried -

```
awk '/:/ {print $2}'
```

But this just gives

```
water
```

I wanted to comma separate it, but there's `colon(:)` after `things`. So, I'm not sure how to separate it.
How do i get the value present in first double quotes?

**EDIT:**

SOLUTION:
I used the below code since I particularly wanted to use awk -

```
awk '/:/' test.txt | cut -d\" -f2
```

Comment: Use `"` as the field separator

Comment: Thanks it worked. I was getting extra spaces though.

Comment: Do you mean the first within a file or the first within each record of a file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solution 1: `awk`**

You can use a single `awk` command:

```
awk -F\" 'index($1, ":"){print $2}' test.txt > outfile
```

See the [online demo](https://ideone.com/H4THB0).

The `-F\"` sets the field separator to a `"` char, `index($1, ":")` condition makes sure Field 1 contains a `:` char (no regex needed) and then `{print $2}` prints the second field value.

**Solution 2: `awk` + `cut`**

You can use `awk` + `cut`:

```sh
awk '/:/' test.txt | cut -d\" -f2 > outfile
```

With `awk '/:/' test.txt`, you will extract line(s) containing `:` char, and then the piped `cut -d\" -f2` command will split the string with `"` as a separator and return the second item. See the [online demo](https://ideone.com/UeF0fB).

**Solution 3: `sed`**

Alternatively, you can use `sed`:

```sh
sed -n 's/^[^"]*"\([^"]*\)".*/\1/p' file > outfile
```

See the [online demo](https://ideone.com/os2gaW):

```sh
#!/bin/bash
s='name
things: "water bottle","40","new phone cover",10
place'
 
sed -n 's/^[^"]*"\([^"]*\)".*/\1/p' <<< "$s"
# => water bottle
```

The command means

- `-n` - the option suppresses the default line output
- `^[^"]*"\([^"]*\)".*` - a POSIX BRE regex pattern that matches

  - `^`  - start of string
  - `[^"]*` - zero or more chars other than `"`
  - `"` - a `"` char
  - `\([^"]*\)` - Group 1 (`\1` refers to this value): any zero or more chars other than `"`
  - `".*` - a `"` char and the rest of the string.
- `\1` replaces the match with Group 1 value
- `p` - only prints the result of a successful substitution.

Answer (score 4):

A solution using the `cut` utility could be

```
cut -d\" -f2 infile > outfile
```

Answer (score 4):

Using `gnu awk` you could make use of a capture group, and use a [negated character class](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html#negated) to not cross the `,` as that is the field delimiter.

```
awk 'match($0, /^[^",:]*:[^",]*"([^"]*)"/, a) {print a[1]}' file
```

Output

```
water bottle
```

The pattern matches

- `^` Start of string
- `[^",:]*:`Optionally match any value except `"` and `,` and `:`, then match `:`
- `[^",]*` Optionally match any value except `"` and `,`
- `"([^"]*)"` Capture in group 1 the value between double quotes

---

If the value is always between double quotes, a short option to get the desired result could be setting the field separator to `"` and check if group 1 contains a colon, although technically you can also get `water bottle` if there is only a leading double quote and not closing one.

```
awk -F'"' '$1 ~ /:/ {print $2}' file
```

Answer (score 4):

With your shown samples, please try following `awk` code.

```
awk '/^things:/ && match($0,/"[^"]*/){print substr($0,RSTART+1,RLENGTH-1)}' Input_file
```

***Explanation:*** In `awk` program checking if line starts with things: AND using `match` function to match everything between 1st and 2nd `"` and printing them accordingly.